# Why "lighting phong" is a must in order to create aminated GIF/movie successfully?

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure, lighting

I have the following Matlab code, which is used for gif and avi animation creation; 
Matlab `imwrite` is used to create frames of the gif; but I found `lighting` command is critical in order to successfully obtain the animated gif.

```
close all
clear all
clc; %
nFrames = 50;
% Preallocate movie structure.
mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata', [],'colormap', []);

% Create movie.
figure('color','white');
Z = peaks(150); surf(Z,Z,'edgecolor','none');
view(3);
axis vis3d tight equal off;
v = axis;
%
for k = 1:nFrames
    clf;
    surf(1.5*sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z,Z,'edgecolor','none');   
    axis(v);
    axis off
    camlight;
    lighting phong
    mov(k) = getframe;
    [Inx,cmap]=rgb2ind(mov(k).cdata,256);
    if k==1
        imwrite(Inx,cmap,'testoutx.gif','gif','DelayTime',0.25,'LoopCount',Inf)    %
    else
        imwrite(Inx,cmap,'testoutx.gif','gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',0.25)    %
    end
end
% Create AVI file.
  movie2avi(mov, 'myPeaks.avi', 'compression', 'None');
```

When I comment "lighting phong", then the obtained gif is static, not animated. It seems only one of the frames is stored. I also tried to use `drawnow` before each `getframe` sentence, but that did not work.  Why? How can I solve the problem without using `lighting`?

The desired gif (obtained from the code above):

[image]

The undesired gif with "lighting phong" commented:

[image]

Comment: mhh it works for me even with lighting phong commented. What software do you use to visualize the gif?

Comment: Probably it is due to the Matlab version difference?

Comment: maybe but I once saw a similar question here where the problem was the web browser used to visualize the gif (i.e. Chrome vs Internet Explorer). Anyhow I use R2013a

Comment: Can you please post your gif file with "lighting phong" commented? Probably this is a Matlab bug for ealier versions; I am using R2010b

Comment: @Benoit_11 - That post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867866/adding-to-matlab-gif-images-using-imwrite-white-images-beyond-certain-point/

Comment: Ah yep that's the one thanks Ray!

Comment: All viewers, MSIE, chrome, XnView work the same for my case. So this is definitely not a problem of GIF viewer.